# in IE 8, do I need absolute path for background images?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Does IE 8 accept relative paths for images or absolute? When I have relative path for in my CSS for background-images they work with the exception of IE 8.  It only shows if I have absolute path.  Does this mean IE 8 wont' accept relative paths or am I missing something?

Comment: IE8 should work with relative or absolute path, add some cod eon how you implemented the image path and where you stored the images

Comment: FWIW, one thing to keep in mind is that if you're using HTTPS, IE8 may show an incorrect "insecure content" warning if you use a relative path for a CSS image resource.

Comment: @ericlaw thx that was the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 8 should work okay with relative image paths. It can be pretty picky with syntax, though. It would be easier to help you debug if you could post your background image CSS, but until then, try looking at these:

http://forum.bytesforall.com/showthread.php?t=15288
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp